# Java 11 + add-export: java.io.IOException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: java, ssl, https, httpclient, tls1.2

How to fix this issue?

It appears with apache httpClient also.

Works well in junit test or from Idea on my local machine **WITHOUT** of

addition of certificates, but fails on remote development environment,

looks like because application on it contains this

```
--add-exports java.base/sun.security.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports java.base/sun.security.pkcs10=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports java.base/sun.security.jca=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports java.base/sun.security.rsa=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports java.base/sun.security.pkcs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports java.base/sun.security.x509=ALL-UNNAMED
```

could not remove it, because current code uses sun.security.*.

It seems to me, these exports **OR** something another leads to

```
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2019-05-25 09:00:19.195 EDT|SignatureScheme.java:282|Signature algorithm, SHA256withECDSA, is not supported by the underlying providers
```

but looks like this is not simple warn, main exception

```
java.io.IOException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:565)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFacade.java:119)...        
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:307)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:285)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:180)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.decode(SSLEngineImpl.java:681)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:636)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:454)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:433)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:634)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader.unwrapBuffer(SSLFlowDelegate.java:480)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader.processData(SSLFlowDelegate.java:389)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader$ReaderDownstreamPusher.run(SSLFlowDelegate.java:263)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SynchronizedRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:175)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:147)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:198)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

Java version is 11.0.3.

Did not helped

```
  SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.3", "SunJSSE");
    sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
    return sslContext;//to http client
```

Comment: There's a pretty good list of ways to debug this in the link at the end.  I think we're going to need to see more info than what you've given to debug this.  https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/sslhandshakeexception-received-fatal-alert-handshake_failure-due-to-no-overlap-in-cipher-suite-943544397.html

Comment: @markspace I added -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose and restart the app, but grep -A 55 "TLSv" APP.log | grep -v "TLSv" | grep -v '^\d*$' does not show useful info.

Comment: (I mean, does not see logs as in mentioned acrticle.)